# VLOOKUP a value to the left of the Lookup_value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

Using Excel, is there any way to use the `VLOOKUP` function to find the date corresponding the minimum and maximum values?

[image]

Comment: You could do it if you added a helper column with the date at the back of the table.

Answer (score 3):

With your layout [@Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29099223/3357935) is correct (you can't) and for the reason stated. INDEX/MATCH may be a suitable alternative but to provide some detail, please try in say I30 copied across and down to suit:

```
 =INDEX($H$6:$H$26,MATCH(I27,I$6:I$26,0))
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to look left using VLOOKUP - it can only look right. You should look at INDEX/MATCH combo to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a helper column to hold the date, you can. In my example I added the helper column in column N. So `column N` also displays the date from `column H`.

```
=VLOOKUP(I27;$I$6:$O$26;7;0)
=VLOOKUP(I28;$I$6:$O$26;7;0)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There **is** an easy solution for this - if you don't insist on using `VLOOKUP()` :-)

1. Above your row 27 enter a new row, repeating the column headings ("Thomson" etc.). You can just use `=I5`, `=J5` and so on.
2. Now enter this formula in I30: `=DGET($H$5:$N$26;1;J27:J28)` ... and drag it to the right.
3. For the maximum values you need to repeat the column headings just above the "maximum" row again.